# Intersection of a line with an Elliptic Curve

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, cryptography, elliptic-curves

I am trying to show that if a line given by $y = mx + b$ intersects an Elliptic Curve given by $E(\mathbb{K}): y^2 = x^3 + Ax + B$ in three points then the line is not tangent to the curve.

Given that char$(\mathbb{K}) \neq 2,3$ and $\mathbb{K}$ is algebraically closed.

Also that if they intersect in two points, the line is tangent to the curve. And if they intersect in one point, the intersection is an inflection point.

I have tried to characterize the points of intersections and compare the slope of the line and curve at those points but I'm not getting anywhere.

any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: It would help if you told us what definition of tangency you are using.

Comment: So basically using this equality $(mx +b)^2 = x^3 + Ax +B$ I tried to characterize the three points of intersection i.e. $(mx +b)^2 - x^3 - Ax -B = (x - x_1)(x - x_2)(x - x_3)$. But I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Have you read my comment?

Comment: Sorry Mariano, I was trying to use the fact that $m$ is the slope of the line and try to somehow compare it with the derivative of the curve at those three points of intersections, i.e. $x_1, x_2, x_3$ I don't think this is a good approach as I have been thinking about it for some times. Do you have any other approach in mind?

Comment: Do you know what the characteristic of a field is?

Comment: char$(\mathbb{K})≠2,3$ and $\mathbb{K}$ is algebraically closed

Answer (score 3):

I will work here over a field of characteristic zero, and in fact, to fix ideas, I will be working just over $\mathbb{Q}$ (you can work out what may happen if the characteristic of the field of definition is positive and $>3$... not much changes). I will also only work out here the following case: *if a line and an elliptic curve intersect in two points, the line is tangent to the curve.*

Let $y=f(x)$ be a function, differentiable at a point $x=a$. Let us define tangent as follows: *we say that a line $L: y=g(x)=mx+n$ is tangent to the graph of $f(x)$ at $x=a$, if* 
$$g(a)=f(a)\quad \text{ and }\quad g'(a)=f'(a).$$

With this definition in mind, let $E/\mathbb{Q}$ be an elliptic curve given by $y^2=x^3+Ax+B$, let $y=f(x)=\sqrt{x^3+Ax+B}$ and let $L: y=g(x)=mx+n$ be a line such that the intersection of $L$ and $E$ intersect exactly at 2 points, $(a_1,b_1)$ and $(a_2,b_2)$. This means that 
$$ g(x)^2 - f(x)^2$$
is a polynomial of degree $3$ with only $2$ roots, namely $a_1$ and $a_2$, so one of them is a repeated root. Let us say $a_1$ is repeated, then
$$ g(x)^2 - f(x)^2=(x-a_1)^2(x-a_2).$$
Thus, if we differentiate at a point $x$ we obtain:
$$ 2g(x)g'(x) - 2f(x)f'(x)=(x-a_1)(2(x-a_2)+(x-a_1)). \quad (\diamond)$$

- If $b_1\neq 0$, evaluate ($\diamond$) at $x=a_1$. Note that $f(a_1)=g(a_1)=b_1$ by assumption, because $E$ and $L$ intersect at $(a_1,b_1)$. If $b_1\neq 0$, then $g'(a_1)=f'(a_1)$, and therefore $L$ is tangent to the graph of $f(x)$ at $x=a_1$ or, equivalently, $L$ is tangent to $E$ at $(a_1,b_1)$.
- Otherwise, if $b_1=0$, then $f(x)$ is **not differentiable** at $x=a_1$, and in fact either (i) $\lim_{x\to a_1^+} f'(x)=\infty$ and $f(x)$ is not defined on $(a_1,\epsilon)$, or (ii) $\lim_{x\to a_1^-} f'(x)=\infty$ and $f(x)$ is not defined on $(\epsilon,a_1)$, for some $\epsilon>0$. Either way, by taking an appropriate limit in ($\diamond$) we find that $\lim_{x\to a_1} g'(x) = \infty$ which implies that $L$ must be a vertical line $x=a_1$. Since in this case ($b_1=0$) the tangent line to $E$ is also $x=a_1$, we conclude that $L$ is tangent to $E$, as claimed.